How can I change the highlighting of Go packages in VS Code?
I want to customize some colors for the editor in VS Code for the Go language. First, I want to start by changing the color for the packages:
package main

(That is, change the word "main" for example). By default it appears with the same color as the Types and I find it somewhat confusing.
So, I tried the following:
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "github.copilot.enable": {
        "*": true,
        "plaintext": false,
        "markdown": false,
        "scminput": false,
        "python": true,
        "go": true
    },
    "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {

    },
    "editor.fontLigatures": false,
    "editor.fontVariations": false,
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[*Light*]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": "ref.matchtext",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#000"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "[*Dark*]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": "ref.matchtext",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#fff"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        // I added this part
        "[*Default Dark Modern*]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": "storage.type.package.go",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#c300ff"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

However, it did not produce any change in the editor. I suppose I should write the correct scope for this case but I don't know where I can look for it (if it is possible to change this).
